# How to set order of functions execution inside useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, promise, react-hooks, es6-promise, use-effect

I need the `useProductList` function  to execute and finish all process before `randomProduct` function will execute.

 For some reason it doesnt work when `fetchData` is a Promise so `randomProduct`  wont be executed. 
I even tried without  `Promise`, nothing did work.

**my custom hook**

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useProductList() {
  const [productList, setProductObjsList] = useState([]);
  const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
  let randomProducts = [];

  const fetchData = () =>
    new Promise(() => {
      arr.splice(1, 7);
      setProductObjsList(arr);
      return arr;
    });

  const randomProduct = (productArr) => {
    //some Math.random() and algorithm  with the productArr
    console.log("randomProduct()", productArr);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then((result) => randomProduct(result));
  }, []);

  return randomProducts;
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-shape-q6i2v?file=/src/App.js)

I will be glad if someone will open my eyes and show me the right way of how to do it.

**EDIT:**
My original **fetchData function**

```
const fetchData = () =>
   {
      fetch('http://localhost:49573/WebService.asmx/ProductList')
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then(
          (xml) =>
            new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml')
              .documentElement.firstChild.textContent
        )
        .then((jsonStr) => JSON.parse(jsonStr))
        .then((data) => {
          setProductObjsList(data);
        })
     });
```

**randomProduct  function**

````
  ```const randomProduct = (productObjectList) => {
    const products = [...productObjectList];
    for (let index = 0; index < products.length; index++) {
      let idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * products.length);
      randomProducts.push(products[idx]);
      products.splice(idx, 1);
    }
  };```
````

Comment: `setProductObjList` needs a new copy of the array every time for React to detect the state change. You don't need all that promise stuff.

Comment: what are you expecting `arr.pop(1,7)` to do? `arr.pop()` has no parameters and removes on element from the end of `arr`

Comment: can you describe in plain words how `useProductList` should function? does it fetch all products then return a single random product?  what is `arr = [1,2,3,...10,11]` supposed to represent? `randomProducts` is initialized as `[]` but it is never updated elsewhere.

Comment: @Mulan Hi, I edited and fixed and updated my question

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what your exact intentions are, but from the name `useRandomProduct` I'm going to make a guess. Top things I'd like for you to take from this answer -

1. You cannot mutate state in React. You cannot use `Array.prototype.pop` and expect your React components to work correctly. If a value is meant to change over the lifetime of the component, use `useState`.
2. Don't put all of your functions inside of the hook. This tendency probably comes from `class`-oriented thinking but has no place in functional paradigm. Functions can be simple and do just one thing.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

// mock products
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

// mock fetch
const fetchData = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(arr)
  })

// random picker
function choose1(all) {
  const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * all.length)
  return all[i]
}

export default function useRandomProduct() {
  // state
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(null)
  // effect
  useEffect(async () => {
    // fetch products
    const products = await fetchData()
    // then choose one
    setProduct(choose1(products))
  }, [])
  // return state
  return product
}
```

To use your new hook -

```js
import { useRandomProduct } from "./useRandomProduct.js"
import Product from "./Product.js"

function MyComponent() {
  const product = useRandomProduct()
  if (product == null)
    return <p>Loading..</p>
  else
    return <Product {...product} />
}
```

Full demo -

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React

// useRandomProduct.js
const arr = [{name:"apple"},{name:"carrot"},{name:"pear"},{name:"banana"}]

const fetchData = () =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000, arr))

function choose1(all) {
  const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * all.length)
  return all[i]
}

function useRandomProduct() {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then(products =>
      setProduct(choose1(products))
    )
  }, [])
  return product
}

// MyComponent.js
function MyComponent() {
  const product = useRandomProduct()
  if (product == null)
    return <p>Loading..</p>
  else
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(product)}</div>
}

// index.js
ReactDOM.render(<div>
  <MyComponent />
  <MyComponent />
  <MyComponent />
</div>, document.querySelector("#main"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your effort, you're right I missed some things here and I edited, fixed and updated my question. I will be glad if you take a look at my two functions how they really are.

Comment: This part I didn't understand `new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000, arr))` what is the `r` ? and why is it print two apples then 1 banana ? and 3. should my `let randomProducts = []` be a state (with `useState()`) ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not resolving the promise. So, until the promise is resolved it will not go inside then() block.

Here's what you have to do

```
const fetchData = () =>
new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  arr.pop(1, 7);
  setProductObjsList(arr);
  resolve(arr);
});
```

A promise has three stage.

1. Pending
2. Resolved
3. Rejected

In your example the promise is always in pending state and never goes to the Resolved state. Once, a promise is resolved it moves to then() block and if it is rejected it moves to catch() block.

Comment: There are other problems here too, like using `arr` not as a part of `useState` and using `arr.pop` which mutates `arr`.

Comment: I edited and updated my question :).  Now where should I put the `catch()` ? and should my `let randomProducts = []` be a state ?